# Prove or disprove that $(a + b)^x \geq a^x + b^x$ for $x \geq 1$ and nonnegative $a, b$?

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to prove or disprove that $(a + b)^x \geq a^x + b^x$ for $x \geq 1$ and nonnegative $a, b$.

It seems intuitively true to me, since it's true for all the positive integer powers. But how would I go about proving that it's true for any arbitrary real number greater than 1?

I thought about using Newton's Generalized Binomial Theorem, but that doesn't quite ever give the elements $a^x$ or $b^x$. I also know that the function $f(y) = y^x$ is convex, but I don't see how I could use that to help here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $(a+b)^{\gamma}\ge a^{\gamma} +b^{\gamma}$ whenever $\gamma\ge1$ and $a,b \ge 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3417748/prove-that-ab-gamma-ge-a-gamma-b-gamma-whenever-gamma-ge1-and) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(a%2Bb)%5Ex%5Cge%20a%5Ex%2Bb%5Ex%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24x%5Cge%201%24&p=1).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Divide by $b^x$, call $c=a/b$. Consider the problem with $x$ fixed and think it as functions of $c$.

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly guessed that we can use the convexity of the function $f(y) = y^x$. For any convex function $f$,
$$f(a) + f(b) = f\left((a + b) \frac{a}{a+b}\right) + f\left((a + b) \frac{b}{a+b}\right) \le \frac{a}{a+b}f(a + b) + \frac{b}{a + b}f(a+b) = f(a + b)$$

Comment: Not all convex functions satisfy this inequality, you can take $f(x) = (x -2)^2$ and $a=b=1$ as a counterexample. How exactly are you using convexity in this proof? It looks like you're just using the fact that $x \mapsto c^x$ is decreasing for $c \in (0, 1)$.

Comment: I just used the definition of convexity in the inequality above!

Comment: I get it now, you're considering convex combinations of $a+b$ and $0$, but you're also using the fact that $f(0)=0$ in our example while making it sound like the inequality is true for all convex $f$, which it isn't. Maybe you should write something like "For any convex function $f$ with $f(0) = 0$, ..."? :)